# looping a data frame while performing if statements

Tags: r, loops, if-statement

R newbie question.
I have a data frame (wealth_df) with each row grouped into a quintile (1 to 5). I want to do loop on each row and find the number of observation each item has for each quintile and store them in a table.

```
    **   Car Bicycle Motorcycle Boat House Quintiles_Score**
     1   0.5   0.2     0.4       0.6  0.8    1
     2   0     0.2     0.4       0     0     2
     3   0.5   0       0.4       0.6   0     1
     4   0     0.2     0         0     0     3    
     5   0     0       0.4       0     0.8   4
     6   0.5   0       0         0     0     4
```

I have done the following but its too tedious since the data frame is big.

```
library(Tidyverse)
#owns a car and in quintile 1
Car_Q1 <- filter(wealth_df, wealth_df$car == 0.5 & wealth_df$Quintile == 1)
No_CarQ1 <- nrow(CarQ1)
print(No_CarQ1)

#owns a boat and in quintile 4
Boat_Q4 <- filter(wealth_df, wealth_df$Boat == 0.8 & wealth_df$Quintile == 4)
No_BoatQ4 <- nrow(BoatQ4)
print(No_BoatQ4)
```

Expected output is:

people owning Cars and are in quintile 1 are: 2

people owning Cars and are in quintile 2 are: 0

people owning Cars and are in quintile 3 are: 0

people owning Cars and are in quintile 4 are: 1

people owning Cars and are in quintile 5 are: 0

Etc

Comment: @Cath, My bad. I have made the edit, any ideas how you would go about it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use function ddply from package plyr to summarize each variable by Quintile_Score:

```
ddply(wealth_df, .(Quintiles_Score..), summarize, 
Car=length(Car[Car!=0]), Bicycle=length(Bicycle[Bicycle!=0]))
```

Comment: Thankssssssssss a lot @user3640617